# Is there a way to make a transactional action in a @Scheduled method?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, datasource

So, my application is multi-tenants based, and I need to apply a transactional request each Sunday at 1:00 PM.
It basically needs to get All resources and create Usage (which is an entity per week) based on the actual Date.

My transactional Method :

```java
/**
* Scheduled to run at 1:00 every sunday
* It should create capacities for all resources that doesn't have any for next years
*/
@Transactional
public void createNewCapacities() throws Exception {
 LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
 System.out.println("Date is :" + now);
 System.out.println("Start of capacities creation...");
 //List<Resource> resources = resourceService.findAll();

 //for(Resource resource : resources){
   //Calendar calendar = calendarService.findCalendarById(resource.getSelectedCalendarId());
     ...
 //}
}
```

My scheduler :

```java
@Service
public class UsageServiceScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private UsageService usageService;

    @Scheduled(cron= "0 0 1 * * SUN")
    public void callScheduledTask() throws Exception {
        usageService.createNewCapacities();
    }
}
```

This throw an Exception:

> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource
> for lookup key [null].

Is there a way to establish a connection with the database during the `@Scheduled` method?

EDIT :
I have both @Transactional and @Scheduled enabled.

TENANT DATA SOURCE PROPERTIES :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tenants")
public class TenantDataSourceProperties {

    private Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Map<Object, Object> getDataSources() {
        return dataSources;
    }

    public void setDataSources(Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataSources) {
        dataSources.forEach((key, value) -> this.dataSources.put(key, convert(value)));
    }

    public DataSource convert(Map<String, String> source) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(source.get("jdbcUrl"))
                .driverClassName(source.get("driverClassName"))
                .username(source.get("username"))
                .password(source.get("password"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

I want my cron job to run for all existing tenants.
Or in other words, get all the dataSources and apply cron job for each db.

Comment: Do you have transactions enabled? If yes, are they working on other places of your code? `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` should work as long as they are placed in different classes (so that the call to the `@Transactional` method goes through the bean proxy).

Comment: Hi & Welcome! ;) Clear case(!?;): Your (default) `DataDource` is tenant-based (how it selects the tenant?) ... does the cron job "select a tenant"? ; if no: use (and propagate) a "super tenant"/n other datasource.